# change date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have date format like **dd.mm.yyyy**

> 24.1.2017 00:00:00

as result I want

> 2017/01/24

I wrote this function to change date to format what I want.

```
 Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
                var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
                var dd = this.getDate();

                return [this.getFullYear(),
                        (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
                        (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
                ].join('/');
            };

            var date = new Date("@Model.BeginTime");

            $("#newsstart").val(date.yyyymmdd());
```

Problem is to convert string to date

```
var date = new Date("@Model.BeginTime");
```

This is invalid date. How can I fix this problem??

Comment: You could try it with the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library

Comment: Are you sure that `"@Model.BeginTime"` is being substituted properly? You should try `var s = "@Model.BeginTime"; console.log("date-string: %s", s); var date = new Date("@Model.BeginTime"); ...` and see what is printed to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library to do convert UTC to formats you want.

You can somewhat like following

`moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Answer (score 1):

Moment is the js to use :)

> Doesnt accept 24.1.2017 00:00:00 format

that is because you are implementing the class wrong or using an invalid format..

By inspecting your code I see that this here  **24.1.2017 00:00:00**
is not matching this pattern **dd.mm.yyyy**

**2017/01/24** is with the pattern **yyyy/MM/DD**   formatted

here a piece of code that can illustrate better:)

```js
var res1 = $("#result"); 

var dateForm = moment('24.1.2017 00:00:00','DD.M.YYYY hh:mm:ss').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
res1.text(dateForm);
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is to convert string to date
>
> ```
> var date = new Date("@Model.BeginTime");
> ```

Your problem is that you are using the Date constructor to parse a string, which is not recommended. Parsing using the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is largely implementation dependent and unreliable. You should use a small function or library to parse it to a date.

Since you're happy to extend *Date.prototype* with a format function, you could also extend *String.prototype* with an equivalent parse, e.g.

```js
String.prototype.parseYMD = function() {
  var b = this.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]);
}

console.log('2017/01/21'.parseYMD().toString());
```

Or you could use a small library like [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha):

```
var date = fecha.parse('2017/01/24','YYYY/MM/DD');
```

#### PS

The specific problem here is that your string is similar to ISO 8601 but not similar enough for some browsers. Some will think it's invalid ISO 8601 and return an invalid date, others will think it's not ISO 8601 and parse it to a date for 24 January, 2017. Both results can be considered correct according to the ECMAScript language specification.